# How to extract template to external file

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

So I'm trying to use handlebars js for a games website, and I want a template for each of the game pages. The problem is I don't know how to extract the file and then use it.

I tried putting the template into a file called template.js and then using a script to call it in, but that didn't work. I tried three other methods, none of them working either.

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div>
          {{name}} {{occupation}}
        </div>
    </script>

    <script>
        //Retrieve the template data from the HTML .
        var template = $('#template').html();

        var context = { "name": "Ritesh Kumar", "occupation": "developer" };

        //Compile the template data into a function
        var templateScript = Handlebars.compile(template);

        var html = templateScript(context);
        //html = 'My name is Ritesh Kumar . I am a developer.'

        $(document.body).append(html);
    </script>
```

This is what I have so far. I'm a beginner so I really don't know what to do.

I want to be able to extract the template to a seperate file so I can reference it in multiple files.

Comment: What are you using to serve the files? `express`, `sails` or something else?

Comment: Ummm idk, im using basic javascript and html? Im hosting with github pages if thats what you mean